# I can not connect database from Netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, database, netbeans, glassfish

I have a  MySQL database on internet. I can reach it by browser and MySQL Workbench successfully. I added database to Netbeans. When I tried to connect database from Netbeans I get this error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException
Error code 0, SQL state 08S01: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 14.047 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1 milliseconds ago.
```

I also tried to connect database by using restful web service. I get this error:

```
GET RequestFailed RequestFailed --> Status: (500) 
Response: {
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT o_id, isim, not, yas FROM ogrenci
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Ogrenci sql="SELECT o_id, isim, not, yas FROM ogrenci")
root cause

Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT o_id, isim, not, yas FROM ogrenci
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Ogrenci sql="SELECT o_id, isim, not, yas FROM ogrenci")
root cause

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
root cause

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 228.471 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 11 milliseconds ago.
root cause

java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 logs.
```

Comment: can you provide the code which you are using to connect to DB.

Comment: There are databases under Services tab on Netbeans. I right-click on Database and then I click New Connection. And then I enter necessary info.

Comment: The connection is closing before you executing the query.

Comment: Do not close the connection and try once. you will get the cause.

Comment: try pinging , check if connection string are correct , the error is mostly because some wrong entry in connection string

Comment: use connection pooling. the problem will get resolved.

Comment: Provide your connection code so that ll help you more..

Comment: @Hussain Akhtar Wahid I think connection string is true. Because when I run SQL queries it works sometimes. But my restful web service never works.

Comment: @Prabhakar Manthena What should I do to ensure that connection remains open

Comment: are you using any framework like hibernate or using plain JDBC ??

Comment: looks to me like a firewall issues meaning the port is blocked

Comment: @Stephan I can connect by using MySQL Workbench and browser. I think the problem is related to Netbeans.

Comment: i see then its something else ... what is the value set for `wait_timeout` variable ?

Comment: @Stephan `wait_timeout` is 10

Comment: try to set it higher like 300 (5 min) and see if it works

Comment: @ekremk Glad it worked, i posted a answer so that other users can see it, don't forget to accept the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to increase the `wait_timeout` mysql variable:

`SET wait_timeout=300;`